# Kingston DDR3 8GB Apple ValueRAM in a PC - doesn't work

Tags: memory

I've tried to install a Kingston DDR3 8GB Apple ValueRAM on a Gigabyte B75N MiniITX board, but it won't boot (black screen, possible beeping - no beeper onboard, no beeper pins).

Afterwards I tried it on another board which gave me the typical 3xBeep&Pause-Sequence.

I tried switching the RAM of the second board to the first and it worked. 
So both boards are working fine.

The Article is named "KTA-MP1066QR/8G".

Could this be a problem related to the voltage? (Actually it should be 1.5V on both sides)
Or is it simply impossible to use this - so called - Apple ValueRAM in a PC?
What else could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Researching the RAM you have specified I found an [Amazon page](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Kingston-KTA-MP1066QR-8G-1066MHz-Registered/dp/B0042LM9D4) which suggests that it is *[registered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory) ECC* RAM.

- *Registered* indicates that is a special high-end type of RAM which is different to normal (unbuffered) RAM. Unfortunately the motherboard you are using [will not work properly](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-034258.htm#server) with registered RAM, it needs unbuffered RAM.
- The *ECC* part indicates that the RAM additionally supports error detection and correction, a feature that your hardware is not designed for and may cause issues.

Basically the RAM you have is designed specifically for a Mac Pro which uses server-grade components (such as Xeon processors) and this makes the RAM requirements quite different.